# Is my grammar not clear enough?

Tags: support, questions, quality-filter

I tried to post this as a question on Stack Overflow:

> I am developing a web application using java.in it i want to send a text message to a mobile.please help me with some example.

but got the following message, and was not allowed to submit:

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

Is my question not clear enough?

Comment: You're focusing on the wrong section. The problem is more with the lack of content and not the grammar. Even asking to "send a text message" is way too broad. What kind of message? SMS? Email? Facebook, Telegram, Whatsapp?

Comment: Just so you know, the -20 downvotes here (at the time of writing) have a special meaning on _Meta_. Here it does not mean that you cannot ask this Meta question - just that people disagree with the contents of it. In other words, people here overwhelmingly agree that your original question does not fit on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is a particularly important part of that error message, "including what you have already tried" - that is what you should be amending in your approach. The quality filter basically says that very short posts cannot reasonably contain a description of what you have done, and thus it prevents you from posting (correctly in this case).

Comment: That question made me punch a baby.  It's your fault that baby got punched, not mine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The exact details of the quality control filter are not public, but your problem is likely due to a combination of factors, including the lack of any code, improper capitalization (it is "I", not "i"), and how short the question is.

However, if what you have quoted in this post is your entire question, the question you want to ask is completely unsuitable for Stack Overflow and would be closed as "Too Broad".

Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, and the users are not usually in the habit of providing example code to very vague specifications.  The site is designed to help programmers solve **specific** programming problems that they encounter with code that they have written (or are trying to write).  You problem is not a specific problem, it is a vague idea.

To make this an on-topic question, you should go back to your research and try to figure out how to try to accomplish your goal.  Had you done a [basic google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20send%20text%20message), you might have found [How to send SMS in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570410/how-to-send-sms-in-java) (which in of itself is not a good Stack Overflow question, but was asked when such questions were acceptable) as well as several libraries that may do what you need.

Once you start writing the code to send the message, if you still run into problems, that is the time to come back to Stack Overflow and ask a question about the specific problem you are having.  Make sure you include:

- An example of your code that replicates the problem (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
- What is it supposed to do
- What is it actually doing
- What error messages, if any, are you getting.

If you do all of that, then I can almost assure that you will not get tripped up by the quality filter.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has happened because you did not supply a code sample of what you have tried to do to solve the problem yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

Here at Stack Overflow we want to help others but we can't do that if you don't tell us what you have done already.